# Problems with the Chroot command

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I am a beginner and I need some help with chroot. My system files are in `/dev/sdc1`. My swap is `/dev/sdc2`. My home partition is `/dev/sdc3`. I booted up the live ubuntu cd. I went to a command line. I guess, I need to mount `/dev/sdc1` where my systems files are at. I tried `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt` and I got a message. "More filesystems detected. This should not happen. use -t  to explicitly specify the file system type." I am not sure what this means. What should I do to mount `/dev/sdc1`?

I am trying to update grub so Ubuntu 12.04 will boot up. I believe the kernel is missing and that is why grub can't find it.

I used this link at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#ChRoot

Any help would be great!

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Answer (score 1):

What does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc` tell you?

If you used the default ext4 filesystem, you can try adding `-t ext4` to the mount command (or equivalently for other FS types). However, the message suggests the filesystem or partition may be corrupt so you may need to run e.g. `sudo fsck /dev/sdc1` to check it.

Comment: I was able to do it. I added -t ext4 and did the chroot and then updated grub and everyting worked! I use your suggestion -t ext4 for the mount command. It worked! I was able to boot into ubuntu 12.04 on sdc1.